# MySQL select best (and oldest) perform per athlete, categories

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to build the SQL query from following table (example):

[Example of table with name "performances"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3RGf.png)

This is table with athletic performances. I want to select the best perform from this table per discipline and set of one or more categories. Each athlete should be only once in result though his best perform value is twice or more in performance table.

[Here is expected result from table "performances"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFtxN.png)

Actually I have this SQL query, but from subquery join all rows with best value for athlete_id and best:

```html
SELECT 

p.athlete_id, p.value 

FROM

(SELECT athlete_id, MAX(value) AS best FROM performances 

WHERE discipline_id = 32 AND category_id IN (1,3,5,7,9) 

GROUP BY athlete_id) f

INNER JOIN performances p 

ON p.athlete_id = f.athlete_id AND p.conversion = f.best

ORDER BY p.value DESC, p.created
```

Please, how can I join only one row for each athlete, which has a oldest created attributte?

Comment: No pictures thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

To get the single row for each `athlete` per `discipline` based on greatest value `value` you can do a self left join, To handle the tie case or if single `athlete` has more than 1 rows having same maximum value you can use case statement to pick the row with oldest date

```
select a.*
from performances a
left join performances b
on a.discipline_id = b.discipline_id
and a.athlete_id = b.athlete_id
and case when a.value = b.value
    then a.created > b.created
    else a.value < b.value
    end 
where b.discipline_id is null
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20d3e3/5)

Further you can add filter in your where clause

```
and a.discipline_id = 32 
and a.category_id IN (1,3,5,7,9)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20d3e3/9)

Comment: Note that this solution scales poorly, but it has the advantage that it will work on even the most ancient version of MySQL

Comment: Thank you a lot, but this solution not work. Maybe I cannot explain what exactly I need.

Comment: @jaromirHloch If you cannot explain then how can we know what is wrong :), Its better if you could add sample data set and your expected output in your question with brief/ criteria for the output it will more helpful if you can setup a sample demo using sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use joins, you can do it with a [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql):

```
SELECT 
  p.athlete_id, 
  p.value 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      athlete_id, 
      value, 
      ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by athlete_id order by value desc, created) rowid 
    FROM 
      performances 
   WHERE 
      discipline_id = 32 AND 
      category_id IN (1,3,5,7,9) 
  ) p 
where 
  p.rowid = 1
```

Comment: Mysql old releases don't offer window functions only new releases from 8+ onwards will have this feature

Comment: ohhhh i'm so sorry i missed the mysql tag... sorry

Comment: Now worries its still correct approach but for future releases

Comment: Thank you a lot, but this solution not work. Maybe I cannot explain what exactly I need.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot, Guys. After your answers I finally found the solution.

```html
SELECT r.* FROM 

(SELECT p.athlete_id, p.conversion, MIN(p.created) AS created FROM

(SELECT athlete_id, MAX(conversion) AS best 
FROM performances 
WHERE discipline_id = 32 AND category_id IN (1,3,5,7,9) 
GROUP BY athlete_id) f

INNER JOIN performances p ON p.athlete_id = f.athlete_id AND p.conversion = f.best
GROUP BY p.athlete_id) w INNER JOIN performances r 

ON w.athlete_id = r.athlete_id AND w.conversion = r.conversion 
AND ((w.created = r.created) OR (w.created IS NULL AND r.created IS NULL))

ORDER BY r.conversion DESC, r.created
```